# How can I hide embedded video popup when clicking outside?

Tags: javascript, html, video, popup

I have this code, but I do not know how to hide the video when clicking outside.

Here is my code:

```js
$(".popup").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $iframe = $("<iframe>").attr("src", $this.data("link")).css({"width": 400, "height": 300});
  var $title = $("<h1>").text($this.data("title"));
  $("#video-view").html($title).append($iframe);
  $iframe.wrap("<div class='class-video'>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="popup" href="#!" data-link="https://www.youtube.com/embed/klModGpSKtc"><img class="img" src="img/annual-smb-report.png"/></a>
<div id="video-view">
</div>
```

I tried everything but clearly I am doing something wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you want to hide the class-video when you click outside of it? You could attach a click event to the body that checks if the class class-video exists and then hide it by setting the css to display none. But why do you want that behaviour? Wouldn't it be better to have a close button?

Comment: It can be a close button also, bear with me as I am a beginner, and I might say stupid things. The close button can be also on the image that opens it.  Can you show me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows the video when clicking on the image and hides when you click anywhere else:

```js
$(".popup").click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var $this = $(this);
  var $iframe = $("<iframe>").attr("src", $this.data("link")).css({"width": 400, "height": 300});
  var $title = $("<h1>").text($this.data("title"));
  $("#video-view").html($title).append($iframe);
  $iframe.wrap("<div class='class-video'>");
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $("#video-view").empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="popup" href="#!" data-link="https://www.youtube.com/embed/klModGpSKtc"><img class="img" src="img/annual-smb-report.png"/></a>
<div id="video-view">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Fabian, this works wonderfully, exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Alina In this particular case it's working because of the iframe. If the popup is `div` whenever you click even in the popup itself it will close the popup. Think if you want this. (Demo on `div` that closes the popup on click **in** the popup: http://jsbin.com/bumonozipo/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add a hidden layer on all the screen. When the user clicks on that layer, you will hide the movie.

keep attention to the `z-index`, it's important.

Like this:

```js
$(".popup").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $iframe = $("<iframe>").attr("src", $this.data("link")).css({"width": 400, "height": 300});
  var $title = $("<h1>").text($this.data("title"));
  $("#video-view").html($title).append($iframe);
  $iframe.wrap("<div class='class-video'>");
  $('.overlay').show();
});

$('.overlay').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('#video-view').html('');
});
```

```css
#video-view {
  z-index: 2;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="popup" href="#!" data-link="https://www.youtube.com/embed/klModGpSKtc"><img class="img" src="img/annual-smb-report.png"/></a>
<div id="video-view">
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```